# MS Access VBA - Write #TextFile

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am exporting data from MS Access into a text file using the Write #TextFile command. Everything works OK except I need one field in the output file without the quotation marks which Write #TextFile puts around the text that is being saved.

My output file looks like the following:

> "D","   105","      ","ARCL","18/11/15","181115","DEPOSIT","99.9"
>   "D","   315","      ","ARCL","18/11/15","181115","DEPOSIT","-9.9"
>   "D","   315","      ","ARCL","18/11/15","181115","DEPOSIT","-90"

and I need it like this:

> "D","   105","      ","ARCL","18/11/15","181115","DEPOSIT",99.9
>   "D","   315","      ","ARCL","18/11/15","181115","DEPOSIT",-9.9
>   "D","   315","      ","ARCL","18/11/15","181115","DEPOSIT",-90

Any idea how to get the above format, please?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the correct data type. Strings are always enclosed in quotation marks. Convert the string to a double

```
Write #TextFile, someStringInQuotationMarks, CDbl(someStringContainingNumber)
```

E.g.: `Write #TextFile, "99.9"` will write `"99.9"` into the file, but `Write #TextFile, CDbl("99.9")` will write `99.9`.